# How to remove empty string in python?

Tags: python, string

I keep getting `ValueError: Could not convert string to float` when I use this code:

```
f = open('temperatuurid.txt')

while True:

    fahren = float(f.readline())
    print(round((fahren-32)*(5/9),2))

f.close()
```

How can i remove empty string that is in the end of .txt document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
f = open('temperatuurid.txt')

while True:
   line = f.readline().strip()
   fahren = float(line) if line else None
   print(round((fahren-32)*(5/9),2)) if line else None

f.close()
```

But that's not about removing empty string, that's only ignoring it, if I correctly understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

```
f = open('file')
m = f.readlines()
for i in m:
    if not i == '\n':
        fahren = float(i)
        print(fahren)
        print((fahren-32)*(5))
f.close()
```

Comment: i like your answer, dont know why the downvote, so have my upvote sir

Comment: I did not downvote, but won't upvote, because `float('')` does not work. Not in python2.7, not in python3. So this does not solve OP's problem

Comment: Ok, with the new edit, the `\n` is taken care of. But why the `strip`? `float('3.2\n')` seems to work perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc:

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the return value unambiguous; if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by '\n', a string containing only a single newline.

so it should look like:

```
f = open('temperatuurid.txt')

for line in f.readLines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    fahren = float(line)
    print(round((fahren-32)*(5/9),2))

f.close()
```

`f.readlines()` returns a list of all lines in file (`while True` is just wrong)

`if not line:` ensures that the we read a value. the doc states:

> If the argument is a string, it must contain a possibly signed decimal or floating point number, possibly embedded in whitespace. ... If no argument is given, returns 0.0.

ps: Avinash Raj did it correct, except that he did not care if the line is empty or not

Comment: An empty line is `'\n'` and `bool('\n') == True`, so it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the empty line is, in fact, empty:

```
print(*[round((float(line)-32)*(5/9),2) for line in f if line != '\n'])
```